# Python: Google sheets API on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, raspberry-pi4

I've written a little program that grabs some data from a Google sheet and running it on my pc works fine. But as soon as I try to run it on my RPi 4 (8gb) it won't go anywhere.
I've narrowed down the issue to 1 line that halts the whole process which is:

```py
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
```

I'm just wondering if it's something on my end or a limitation on the RPi. PS, the credentials are correct.

(Whole block for reference, it prints "got here alright" but never "got here")

```py
def getHourData():
    print("got here alright")
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
    print("got here")
    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range='Medics!G4:P').execute()
    print("got here too")
    values = result.get('values', [])
```

Comment: Are there any errors, or does it just stop with 0 exit code?

Comment: How do you define variable `creds`?

Comment: There are no errors, the program doesn't stop. It seems that it just hangs there on that function. @Blue

Comment: SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('keys.json', scopes=SCOPES) @NikkoJ.

Comment: @PiratePie - Have you tried checking if `creds` returns credentials after declaring it?

Comment: @NikkoJ. yea I tried that, returns everything fine.

Comment: Since the code is working, this might be a hardware issue. You may contact the support for Raspberry Pi to know if the product supports such API.